# Stopwatch: measuring time and restart immediately without race condition

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

i have a question regarding the Stopwatch class in the .net framework. I want to measure the time a loop iteration takes ( timing in a game )

```
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start(); // Edited this in, forgot about that
while(true)
{
    var timespan = timer.Elapsed;
    timer.Restart();
    // do something with the timespan

    // Do some work here
}
```

I'm worried that between the measuring and the restart a context switch could happen and some "time" will be lost.
Does anyone know a way to measure and restart the timer in an atomic way?

Edit: Solutions without a Stopwatch are also welcome

Comment: put timer.start above while loop,timer.stop bellow and create timespan variable = timer.Ellapsed,if its to record while loop time.

Comment: I dont want to measure the whole while loop but only every iteration. This is used for a game loop and probably it is not important that the "context switch time" isnt in it. It is just that i would like to have it as precise as possible. And think about this: What if my thread is low priority and a high priority thread starts and my low priority gets no cpu cycles for 2 minutes or something( just made up :) ). This would impact the measurement alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to restart the timer. You can just remember the last measurement of Elapsed in a variable and then always take the difference. Something like (you have to also take care of the first iteration):

```
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
var lastElapsed = timer.Elapsed;
while(true)
{
    var newLastElapsed = timer.Elapsed;
    var timespan = newLastElapsed - lastElapsed;
    lastElapsed = newLastElapsed;
    // do something with the timespan

    // Do some work here
}
```

However, why do you care that some time elapsed between taking the measurement of Elapsed and restarting the timer? Are you interested in only measuring the "Do some work here" part or also measuring the "do something with the timespan" part?

Comment: I just also came to this solution. What i want to do is actually emulate a timer. I'm adding the time of every iteration to another timespan and when this timespan then exceeds some threshhold a method is fired. In my case this is a gameloop with a fixed timestep that fires update and draw at different intervals

Comment: While this is certainly feasible, there's no longer any reason to even have a `Stopwatch` instance doing subtraction internally.  Just do `lastTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();` and `newTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp(); timespan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(newTimestamp - lastTimestamp); lastTimestamp = newTimestamp;`  Eliminates the needless repetitive subtraction of whatever the timestamp was when the Stopwatch object was first created.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
var previous = timer.elapsed;
while(!done)
{
    var current = timer.Elapsed;
    var elapsed = current - previous;
    previous = current;
    // use elapsed
    // do the rest of your work
}
```

Sorry for the formatting, Ill fix it when I'm at a real computer.